# Html - Invisible alternative text

Tags: html

First of all I apologize for the silly question. I'm trying to make my site accessible but I need to put alternative text in a line like this:

```
<a id="logo" class="logo" href="<!-- IF U_SITE_HOME -->{U_SITE_HOME}<!-- ELSE -->{U_INDEX}<!-- ENDIF -->" title="<!-- IF U_SITE_HOME -->{L_SITE_HOME}<!-- ELSE -->{L_INDEX}<!-- ENDIF -->">{SITE_LOGO_IMG}</a>
```

But I don´t want that the alternative text to appear in the site, and I don't know how to make invisible alternative text.

Comment: No, I need to change in that code

Comment: alt text only comes up if the logo doesn't load

Comment: @Rachel Gallen can you help me please? How can I put alt text in that line, I alread try put alt="Logo", but this make image desapear

Comment: Thank you for all the helping, I already solve the problem with a hidden div.